# How to export specific columns from a SQL table

Tags: mysql, database-design, phpmyadmin

I am cleaning some data bases and was wondering that if there is any proper way to export any single column and all it's entries from a SQL table.

Being specific, I am dealing with SQL tables in phpmyadmin; if i am not wrong, there must be a SQL query for such tasks.

Comment: No, you must create such query by self.

Answer (score 3):

Using phpMyAdmin run a SQL query against the table that you want a column of data from and select only that column (something along the lines of `SELECT cas_number FROM analytes`).

Scroll to the bottom of the results and click on Export. The only thing that will be exported is the column of data that was selected.